# Is signal point in a relay isolated from power points?

Tags: arduino, relay, signal, arduino-uno

I am thinking of using a 5v relay switch to isolate some 6V solenoids and a motor from my arduino circuit. Can I use my 6V adaptor to also power the relay and use digital output of arduino to signal open or close? Are the signal point isolated from power points?

[image]

Comment: Give us information about your 6V adapter (its Manufacturer number). Same for the relay you want to use. Normally the relays do isolate the signal from the control switch/power. But we need to check the datasheets to be sure. We also need to know hiw much current your adaptor can provide, so that we know its enough to drive the solenoid

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios I updated the adaptor image with technical specs in my question. I don't mind burning up my adaptor, its quiet cheap and I'll get a 2A adaptor if it burns out. I am more concerned about isolating my arduino as much as possible. I could power the 5 way 5v relay with the arduino but if I can power it externally and just use the signal from the Arduino then I'd be very happy. I'll be receiving my relay in a few hours so can't share specs yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the relay to isolate it. Note that in the drawing, the two negatives of the supply are not connected. Do not connect the GND/negative of the Arduino to the negative of the power supply if you need isolation.

Make sure to include these diodes! These are called freewheeling/flyback diodes. The purpose of these are when an inductive load is suddenly turned off, there is energy stored in the inductor and the current will continue to flow and will need somewhere to go. The diode allows it to recirculate through the inductor until all of the stored energy is dissipated.

If you're driving the relay coil directly from the Arduino, make sure to look at what the current through the coil of the relay is by checking the datasheet of the relay. You'll need to make sure that the coil doesn't draw too much current. You could also measure the resistance of the relay coil and do ohms law by dividing the voltage you're driving the coil with by the resistance of the coil.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUfTRb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

They will be electrically isolated on separate supplies, but not magnetically isolated unless you  attenuate with twisted pair at right angles from motor pair. STP or shielded twisted pair is even better.

This is to supplement the 1st answer which is basic a basic EMF clamp. A similar clamp is needed for the relay load  and solenoid load and possible if the cables are not shielded to reduce arc voltage from resetting the uC. A small R snubber or RC , RF cap suppression may be needed to suppress noise egress or ingress.